# Constraints to childViewController, that include another view

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, ios-autolayout

I have a parent viewController and add child view controller on it.
But the issue is that I need to connect childViewControolers view top to searchBar (it means another view), that locates on parentViewControoler view.

The question is : does it possible or I do smth wrong?

below is my code:

```
    parentView.addSubview(childView)

    childView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))

    parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .top, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: mySearchBar, attribute:  .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 12.0))
    parentView.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: childView, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: parentView, attribute: .bottom, multiplier: 1, constant: 0.0))
```

after applying these constraints childViewController is not shown.

Thank you in advance for any advice or suggestion.

I added two screen shots: the first one its the viewcontroller at the beginning it has view with searchBar and bellow it tableViewController.

> [image: Blockquote]

after activation of search, I need to perform the action described above. So the parentViewController is this controller and parent view is this controllers view. In order to perform proper animation i want to connect childview controllers view top to search bar bottom.[image]

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you have to call `.isActive = true` at the end of each of your constraints?

Comment: @sdasdadas, when i substitute constraint view searchView on parentView, this works perfectly, but with searchView- it doesnt. Thanks a lot, but your suggestion doesnt work, unfortunatly.

Comment: @Melany - Just out of curiosity, how is `mySearchBar` set up? Is a custom search bar? Is it setup using auto layout? In my experience when you try to use `NSLayoutConstraints` on view's that aren't set using auto layout it doesn't always work.

Comment: @Pierce mySearchBar - its custom searchbar, that use autolayouts and lies on view.

Comment: @Melany - Is there any way you could add a screenshot? So we could see where you expect it to be, and the layout if it's surrounding views?

Comment: @Pierce i added pictures if it could help I will be thankfull!!!

Comment: @Pierce finally I connected it, but visual effect is not the one I expect

Comment: @ Melany - So what exactly is the problem now? You finally got the auto layout constraint issue resolved, but now your custom searchBar doesn't look right? Is that what you're saying?

Comment: @Pierce, the issue was to make the transition animation smooth, but we decided to leave it as it is , so it looks like feature)))